# LINQ query returning null when requesting bytes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to make a downloadable track with MVC.
This is the code I have:

```
public ActionResult DownloadTrack(int albumid, int trackid)
    {
        var track = (from x in database.songs
                     where x.ALBUM_ID == albumid &&
                     x.TRACK_ID == trackid
                     select x).First();
        Byte[] Song = track.MP3;
        return File(Song, ".mp3", "test");
    }
```

when the code arrives at Byte[] Song it says track.MP3 = null
But when I query my database it says it is filled...

Comment: Have you profiled the query that this is generating?

Comment: Agree with @IronMan84 : you should first check that you get the expected track (BTW, you should use .FirstOrDefault() and handle the track == null case)

Comment: @IronMan84.  I have never done query profiling.  How is that done? and can you do it on SQL Compact Edition?

Comment: @Lourens what is the server type for MP3?

Comment: @Lourens Are the other fields on `track` as you'd expect, or are they empty, too? If empty, perhaps the query as a whole is failing.

Answer (score 0):

The **First** operator returns the first element of a sequence or the first element of a sequence matching a predicate, depending on the prototype used.

**BTW:** 
ArgumentNullException is thrown if any arguments are null.
InvalidOperationException is thrown if the source sequence is empty or if the predicate never returns true.

So, most probably the criteria used in where clause does not produce any result.

**Suggest the following:**

**a) In case you are using MS SQL Server, Use SQL Profiler and make sure correct SQL is applied to DB (SQL generated from LINQ)**

- Open SQL Server Management Studio
- Go to Tools – SQL Server Profiler
- Agree with defaults in the opened Trace Properties’ dialog, click ‘Run’
- Run the above mentioned LINQ and investigate the SQL statement in SQL Profiler
  (You can copy and paste the SQL from the profiler into DB directly, run and see whether
  it produces the desired result or not, and if not revise the LINQ).

**b) Suggest using FirstOrDefault, and handle the returned null**